# Get the values from an array

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-table

I have a table in my jsp:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Recompensa</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="amount">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="text">
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send('table')"/>
```

I write something in the boxes, and press Send, and the send Javascript method is called.

Javascript send method, which iterates through rows and cells, and stores the values in an Array:

```
function send(tableID) {


        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);


        var array= new Array();

        for (var i = 1;i<table.rows.length; i++){

            var row = table.rows[i];
            for (var j = 0;row.cells.length; j++){

                alert("added to array: "+row.cells[j].innerHTML);
                array.push(row.cells[j].innerHTML);

            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting "`<input name="amount" type="text">`" in the alert. I have tried using `row.cells[j].firstChild.innerHTML`, receiving undefined.

What am I doing wrong? how could I get what the user writes in the textboxes?

PS: I'm using Firefox to test. Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: Your first problem is in the second loop. You don't have a stopping condition. It should be `for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++)`

Comment: Oh, right, i corrected it. Its not the problem I am currently facing, but thank you for pointing me that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
alert("added to array: " + row.cells[j].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value);
```

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4TjYH/

**EDIT:** By the way, the code you posted may have been stripped down for simplicity, but if it's your actual code you can really simplify it:

```
function send(tableID) {
    var array = new Array(),
        inputs = document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        alert("added to array: " + inputs[i].value);
        array.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still has the same error because of the loop condition. Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h693g/1/

Comment: I added an edit that will simplify your code. It's a bit cleaner, unless you had a reason for looping through the table cells.

Answer (score 2):

In the second loop is an error:

```
for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++){
```

"j <" was missing. the same problem was in the answer of Gavin: here the edit fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h693g/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want what the user has typed in the textboxes, you can assign ids to each textbox and use getElementById():

```
 <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text">

 var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
 var text = document.getElementById("text");
```

Then just push those two values on your array:

```
array.push(amount.value);
array.push(text.value);
```

You can put this logic in a loop, looping through an array of element ids or something if you didn't want to write similar code over and over.

Comment: The table has a dynamic number of rows, so I dont know how many rows it will have when the user hits Send :) I didnt said that because I thought its not important for the problem I was facing.